# Making a Diagonal matrix with desired shape

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.7

How to make a random elements digonal matrix in a numpy array with the desired shape, for example I want to make F to be a numpy array with shape (3, 2, 4, 4), and the diagonal matrix dimensions 4*4 like this:

```
  F= np.array([[[[  a,  0,  0,  0],
                  [ 0,  b,  0,  0],
                  [ 0,  0,  c,  0],
                  [ 0,  0,  0,  d]],

                 [[e, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, f, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, g, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, h]]],

                [[[i, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, j, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, k, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, l]],

                 [[m, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, n, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, o, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, p]]],

                [[[q, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, r, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, s, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, t]],

                 [[ u,  0,  0, 0],
                  [ 0,  v,  0, 0],
                  [ 0,  0,  w, 0],
                  [ 0,  0,  0, x]]]]
```

is there any simple and handy command to do this instead of performing for loops,
for example something like this simple command:

```
F=(np.arange(96)).reshape(3, 2, 4, 4)
```

Comment: What's the logic for 1, 2, 3 and 91 being in the matrix?

Comment: `np.eye(4,4)` creates a 4x4 diagonal matrix which you can multiply to a vector to obtain the different diagonal values.

Comment: @slothrop No logic behind the numbers in the main diagonal just random numbers

Comment: @learningstatistics right: the numbers I'm referring to are those **not** in the main diagonal. So 1, 2, 3 and 91 in version 1 of the question. And 91 in version 2 of the question.

Comment: Thanks for noting I corrected this , it should be zero

Comment: You should wait for new version numpy 2 released February 1st, 2024.

Comment: @toyotaSupra so it will have a new command for diagonal matrix?

Comment: Here is link: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/numpy-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `np.fromfunction`. We can write a custom function which will be given input arrays `x`, `y`, `z` and `w`, all of which have the same shape as the target array, with the property that every element of `x` has value equal to its index in dimension 0, every element of `y` has value equal to its index in dimension 1, and so on.

Then the diagonal elements that you're interested in are just those for which `z==w`. We can use `np.where` to construct an array in which those elements are random, and the others zero.

```
def random_if_diagonal(x, y, z, w):
    return np.where(z==w,
                    np.random.default_rng(seed=42).uniform(size=w.shape),
                    np.zeros_like(w))

shape = (3, 2, 4, 4)
arr = np.fromfunction(random_if_diagonal, shape=shape)
print(arr)
```

The random values here are floats between 0 and 1. If you prefer, you can scale them by multiplying, and convert them to int.

Result:

```
[[[[0.77395605 0.         0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.97562235 0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.37079802 0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.         0.22723872]]

  [[0.55458479 0.         0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.35452597 0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.466721   0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.         0.96750973]]]


 [[[0.32582536 0.         0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.47570493 0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.7002651  0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.         0.2883281 ]]

  [[0.6824955  0.         0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.66485086 0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.139797   0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.         0.76499886]]]


 [[[0.63471832 0.         0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.43671739 0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.05830274 0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.         0.78389821]]

  [[0.66431354 0.         0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.09004786 0.         0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.1523121  0.        ]
   [0.         0.         0.         0.63028259]]]]
```

It's worth saying this isn't the most memory-optimal way of doing it, because it constructs an entire random matrix and an entire zero matrix of the same shape as the target. If the size of array in your example is a realistic use case though, that shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. the shape could be something like (3, 2, 216 ,216) or may be (3, 2, 512, 512) is it ok for the performance?

Comment: From a brief test, it still seems pretty quick for those sizes. (3, 2, 512, 512) is 1.5 million elements, so a few megabytes of data only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that is more compact and I think more "numpythonic":

```py
import numpy as np

shape = (3, 2, 4, 4)

values = np.random.random(np.prod(shape[:-1]))

data = np.eye(shape[2], shape[3]) * np.ones((shape[0], shape[1], 1, 1))
data[np.nonzero(data)] = values

with np.printoptions(precision=2):
    print(data)
```

Which prints:

```
[[[[0.55 0.   0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.96 0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.29 0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.   0.51]]

  [[0.98 0.   0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.08 0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.16 0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.   0.83]]]


 [[[0.83 0.   0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.16 0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.85 0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.   0.09]]

  [[0.37 0.   0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.35 0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.59 0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.   0.84]]]


 [[[0.29 0.   0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.85 0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.41 0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.   0.51]]

  [[0.46 0.   0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.86 0.   0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.73 0.  ]
   [0.   0.   0.   0.71]]]]
```

The key ideas here are:

- Create a version of `data` with unit matrices using `np.eye` and broadcasting
- Find the non-zero values and use those as indices to set the random values

I hope this helps!